# Static IP address and Business Regulations

Tags: discussion

On superuser, can I ask about the static IP's selling conditions and why they need to have business regulations on it?

Comment: A QA that properly explains IPv4 exhaustion *could* work. Something as specific as you outlined wouldn't work.

Comment: It sounds like a broad question to be honest.

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe so. We are about questions with problems on your computer that you're using, for the most part. Asking about why companies charge for certain things falls outside our scope in general.

You could certainly try in Chat, but I don't know how much of our audience would have an authoritative answer for it.